# SELECT * FROM comicinfo WHERE ComicTitle LIKE '%%' AND Genre LIKE Genre=CrimeDatabase access failed: Unknown column 'Crime' in 'where clause'

Tags: php

```
SELECT * FROM comicinfo WHERE ComicTitle LIKE '%%' AND Genre LIKE Genre=Crime
```

> Database access failed: Unknown column 'Crime' in 'where clause'

I receive the error mentioned above,

```
$comic_genre_SQL =(($comic_genre=="fantasy"?"Genre=Fantasy":$comic_genre=="crime")?("Genre=Crime"):("TRUE"));

$query = "SELECT * FROM comicinfo WHERE ComicTitle LIKE '%$comic_name%' AND Genre LIKE $comic_genre_SQL";
```

this is a portion of the code. If I could receive some help >_<

Comment: `AND Genre LIKE Genre=Crime` should be `AND Genre LIKE '%Crime%'` (or `AND Genre='Crime'`)

Comment: don't use double quotes for values, use single quotes. double quotes get interpreted as table names in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use quote just like your previous LIKE part, and dont forget the operator https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comicinfo WHERE ComicTitle LIKE '%$comic_name%' AND Genre LIKE '%$comic_genre_SQL%'";
```